# Empty email field exception with Parse PFSignUpViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse's built-in signup view controller on iOS, with the `PFSignUpViewController` instance set to use `emailAsUsername`. With this setting, it correctly sets the username to user's email, but sets email to the empty string. This is a big problem because it also throws an exception if two users try to sign up with the same email.

I have tried copying username into email field in the delegate method `shouldBeginSignUp`, which gets called after the signup fields are filled in but before signup happens. For some reason, the email is still set to empty string.

I have also tried creating a cloud code `saveBefore` trigger to update the email field server side before it is saved. But Parse doesn't allow the field to be updated in cloud code -- supposedly because it might not be unique :)

A workaround is to set email to username as soon as the signup process succeeds, but this obviously fails if two signups happen at about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Both `PFLogInViewController` and `PFSignUpViewController` have a property called `emailAsUsername`. You can simply set this to `true`.

> Whether to prompt for the email as username on the login view. If set to YES, we’ll prompt for the email in the username field. This property value propagates to the attached signUpController. By default, this is set to NO.

Links to the references:

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInViewController.html#/c:objc(cs)PFLogInViewController(py)emailAsUsername

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFSignUpViewController.html#/c:objc(cs)PFSignUpViewController(py)emailAsUsername